# Jenkins pipeline stages - passing whole file

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

Running a Jenkins pipeline (based on Groovy) with stages containing many nodes, I need to pass a list from some file on NodeA on stageA to nodeB on StageB.

In stageA NodeA I run

```
DEVenv = readFile 'somefile.txt'
```

In stageB I run

```
println DEVenv
```

So far so good, I get the output in the console.

Now how to pass the output of that `println DEVenv` to a file?

```
println DEVenv > otherfile.txt
```

doesn't do the trick :-(

I'm sure it's not such a big deal but I've been churning the internet for a couple of hours to no avail.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can write content to a file using the [`writeFile`](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-basic-steps/#code-writefile-code-write-file-to-workspace) step:

```java
writeFile file: 'otherfile.txt', text: DEVenv
```

Btw. In order to transfer workspace contents to another node, you are supposed to use the [`stash/unstash`](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-basic-steps/#code-stash-code-stash-some-files-to-be-used-later-in-the-build) steps (not sure, if you use that already).

Comment: I'm sorry, new to this, How would I go about using stash unstash? and umm, won't text: DEVenv write the word "DEVenv" into the file, rather than the whoel value of the DEVenv variable?

Comment: Give it a try.. `DEVenv` is the name of the variable, compared to `"DEVenv"`. Some information regarding `(un)stash` can be found [here](https://www.cloudbees.com/blog/parallelism-and-distributed-builds-jenkins). You will need that to copy the workspaces from Node A to Node B.

Comment: Cheers, that works. Thanks, but I'm still stuck with an extra bit of groovy joy.. On to the next question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40827434/jenkins-pipeline-in-stage1-read-number-from-file-in-stage2-within-node-n